# Application tried to present a nil modal view controller on target "Current View Controller"

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with xib , when I try to present a storyboard view on it , it crashes.

I present it using this

```
 UIViewController * buddiesOrFacebook = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuddiesFBFriends"] ;
 [self presentViewController:buddiesOrFacebook animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Always post the complete error message when posting a question like this.

Comment: What is the crash log you are getting?

Comment: Did you check in the debugger to make sure that `buddiesOrFacebook` is not nil?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check these things

1. Check the identifier of the viewcontroller, if it is the same that you mentioned in storyboard[image]
2. Make sure that your buddiesOrFacebook is not nil. Set a breakpoint on that line and on the debug area at the bottom see whether the object is not nil. If it is nil then problem lies in the storyboard connection
3. If your current viewcontroller is not launched from storyboard then get storyboard object like this :

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
   UIViewController * buddiesOrFacebook = [storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BuddiesFBFriends"] ;
   [self presentViewController:buddiesOrFacebook animated:YES completion:nil];
   ```

**Swift Update:**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil)
var buddiesOrFacebook = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BuddiesFBFriends")
self.presentViewController(myViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank You very much..working fine on instantiate view identifier name insert on storyboard...!!!!

Comment: Thanks bro. You save my day.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that works for Me is :
[image]

You have to mark the box is Initial View Controller to make it work.